# Binary digits in decimal

Tags: binary, digits

How do you represent (decimal) integer 50 in binary?
How many bits must be "flipped" in order to capitalize a lowercase 'a' that is represented in ASC11? 
How do you represent the (decimal) integer 50 in, oh, "hexadecimal," otherwise known as base-16? Recall that decimal is simply base-10, and binary is simply base-2. Infer from those base systems how to represent this one?
Please answer these questions for me.HELP.

Answer (score 0):

### Converting from decimal to another base

Here some tips for you regarding conversion to binary:

- What is `50 mod 2`? What about `25 mod 2` and then `12 mod 2`? What are your results if you continue this?
- What does any number `mod 2` (always) return as result? - `1` or `0`
- Do you realise any patterns? - You get the reversed binary number as result

Test case 50:

```
50 mod 2 = 0 - 6th digit
25 mod 2 = 1 - 5th digit
12 mod 2 = 0 - 4th digit
 6 mod 2 = 0 - 3rd digit
 3 mod 2 = 1 - 2nd digit
 1 mod 2 = 1 - 1st digit
```

The remainders of the divisions concatenated and reverses are: `110010`, which is `50` in binary.

Can this be also transformed to further bases? - Yes, as we see with trying to convert `50` to hexadecimal:

```
50 mod 16 = 2 - 2nd digit
 3 mod 16 = 3 - 1st digit
```

The remainders again concatenated and reversed are `32`, which conveniently is `50` in hexadecimal.

In general we can say to convert a number to an arbitrary base you must take the remainder of the number and the base and then divide the number by the base and do the same thing again. In a program this would look something like:

```
while the number is greater 0 do:
    result = (number mod base) + result;
    number = number div base;
```

### Converting from any base to decimal

How do you convert a number from an arbitrary base into base 10? First let us do a test case with binary. Lets take the `50` from the previous example: `110010`

The method to convert from binary is multiplying every digit with the base to the power of the position of it in the number and adding up the result. The enumeration of the positions begins with `0` at the least significant digit. Our previous number would then look something like this:

```
1 *2^5 + 1 *2^4 + 0 *2^3 + 0 *2^2 + 1 *2^1 + 0 *2^0
```

What simplifies to:

```
32 + 16 + 2 = 50
```

It also works with any other base, like our `32` from the previous example:

```
3 *16^1 + 2*16^0 = 48 + 2 = 50
```

In program this would look something like this:

```
from end of number to beginning do:
    result = result + digit * (base ^ position)
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you some:

Binary is only made up of 1's and 0's.
This may help you understand binary conversion [image: [conversion table]]

Decimal is 0-9

Hexadecimal is 0-9, then A-F (so A would represent 10, B would be 11, etc up to F which is 15)